# Substring selection with Unicode multibyte characters in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, emoji

I am a bit confused about how Python 3 handles unicode multibyte characters. Here's an example with an emoji:

```
In [1]: print('☺️')
☺️

In [2]: print(len('☺️'))
2

In [3]: print('☺️'[0])
☺

In [4]: print('☺️'[1])
️

In [5]: print(len('‍'))
4
```

Since I'm working on a small hobby project dealing with emojis, this causes certain problems for me since I would prefer to deal with emojis as single character strings, rather than treating them as multicharacter strings as Python 3 seems to do. Why doesn't Python 3 recognize this as a single character, and how do I go about and work with emojis in the manner I would prefer?

If this is rather a problem with my terminal or REPL, I'm using the macOS Sierra terminal with iPython 5.1.0.

Comment: ☺️ is represented by *two* bytes using the UTF-16 scheme.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Sure, but it is still a single character right? UTF-(8|16) supports multibyte characters.

Comment: @MarounMaroun That's four bytes in UTF-16.

Comment: "Unicode multibyte" is a misnomer, and @Maroun UTF-16 has nothing to do with it.  Unicode units are code points (no storage or encoding implied) and more than one can be used to describe a single  character.  A series of code points used to describe one character is a *grapheme cluster*.

Comment: Think of the code points in a Unicode string like the numbers is a Python list: `[1,2,5000000000]`.  How many bytes per number?  Answer: don't care.  When you do care, is when you write the numbers or Unicode strings to a terminal, or file, or network socket. For Unicode strings you `.encode()` them into bytes, specifying an appropriate encoding to convert the code points to one or more bytes.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Why not? For example, if we're using UTF-32, "a" will be represented by 4 bytes, while using UTF-8 reduce it to only one byte. Isn't it the same here?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Unicode strings are not encoded.  UTF-32 is an encoding to translate Unicode strings (containing code points) into byte strings (containing bytes).  So `len()` of a Unicode string returns number of codepoints.  A two-code point Unicode string returns length 2, but encoded as a UTF-32 byte string it would return 8.  Encoded as UTF-8 would return 2-8 depending on the code points since UTF-8 uses different numbers of bytes for different code point ranges.

Comment: Also note before Python 3.3, Unicode string were stored internally in CPython as UTF-16LE, and `len()` returned number of UTF-16 code units used.  Some Unicode code points use two UTF-16 code units, making `len()` of Unicode strings confusing.  Python 3.3+ fixed this, and `len()` returns Unicode code point count instead.  See [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/).

Comment: If this is still confusing see [Ned Batchelder: Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) and [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets No Excuses](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: @MarkTolonen Valuable information, thanks.

Comment: See: [Let’s Stop Ascribing Meaning to Code Points](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/14/stop-ascribing-meaning-to-unicode-code-points/)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your both strings ('☺️' and '‍') contain one invisible character each:

```
>>> '☺️'[0]
'☺'
>>> '☺️'[1]
'️'
>>> '☺️'[1].encode('unicode_escape')
b'\\ufe0f'                             # !!!!!!!!!!
>>> '‍'[0]
''
>>> '‍'[1]
''
>>> '‍'[2]
'\u200d'                               # !!!!!!!!!!
>>> '‍'[3]
''
```

The character `'\ufe0f'` (<kbd>U+FE0F</kbd>)  is [Variation Selector-16](https://codepoints.net/U+FE0F?lang=en) codepoint that

> may change the appearance of the preceding character. If that is a symbol, dingbat or emoji, `U+FE0F` forces it to be rendered as a colorful image as compared to a monochrome text variant.

The character `'\u200d'` (<kbd>U+200D</kbd>)  is the [Zero Width Joiner](https://codepoints.net/U+200D?lang=en).

Comment: That's interesting, so Python 3 actually _does_ treat the emojis correctly from a unicode standpoint; an emoji really is a multicharacter symbol? Seems like I have to create a subclass of the String class that will look out for the emoji edge cases...?

Comment: Characters, and especially emoji, can consist of an arbitrary number of code points. The technical term for such a group is a *grapheme cluster*. [Some examples here.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unicode/6485/characters-can-consist-of-multiple-code-points#t=201701222129426089213) I think there are a few questions on SO about how to iterate over those grapheme clusters.

Comment: The `regex` 3rd party module has `\X` to match grapheme clusters.

Comment: @JimmyC *an emoji really is a multicharacter symbol?* In your first example it is, but it doesn't need to be. I guess the '\ufe0f' codepoint was included with the emoji when you copied it.

Comment: @Leon I didn't copy the emoji, I used the emoji keyboard available on macOS. If the \ufe0f codepoint isn't included, ☺️ becomes ☺.

Comment: @JimmyC "...☺️ becomes ☺" my Firefox shows no difference between the two, though I admit that certain emoji-oriented systems make the visual distinction conspicuous